# add line 99 quartile to seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
          A   B   C  D  
sample1   1   50  20 10 
sample2   30 10  30 0
sample3   4  15 20 5
```

I made boxplots with this data `sns.boxplot(data)`, but I need to set individual thresholds at 99 percentile in each sample.

I extracted the percentiles with: `per = df.quatile(.99)`, but I don't know how to add them.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46486934/python-seaborn-pointplot-and-boxplot-in-one-plot-but-shifted-on-the-x-axi. Create a dataframe with you percentile values. The mean of the percentile values will then again be the percentile which will be plotted.